# MySQL join with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    A.player, A.score, B.kills, C.deaths, D.killed AS most_killed, D.kills AS most_killed_count, E.player AS most_killed_by, E.kills AS most_killed_by_count
FROM
(SELECT player, score FROM pvpr_scores WHERE player = 'Neutronix' AND milestone = 'default') AS A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT player, COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE player = 'Neutronix' AND milestone = 'default') AS B ON B.player= A.player
LEFT JOIN (SELECT killed, COUNT(*) AS deaths FROM pvpr_kills WHERE killed = 'Neutronix' AND milestone = 'default') AS C ON C.killed= A.player
LEFT JOIN (SELECT player, killed, COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE player = 'Neutronix' GROUP BY killed ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1) AS D ON D.player= A.player
LEFT JOIN (SELECT player, killed, COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE killed = 'Neutronix' GROUP BY player ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1) AS E ON E.killed= A.player
```

However, if one of these subqueries return null, the entire query fails. I would like to have the null queries instead make those columns null in the returned result set (1 row).

If I changed `Neutronix` to something not in the database, like `dfdsjf`, there is an error.

EDIT: Here's the fix I did.

```
SELECT
    A.player, A.score, B.kills, C.deaths, D.killed AS most_killed, D.kills AS most_killed_count, E.player AS most_killed_by, E.kills AS most_killed_by_count
FROM
(SELECT player, score FROM pvpr_scores WHERE player = 'Gutterknife' AND milestone = 'default') AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE player = 'Gutterknife' AND milestone = 'default') AS B ON TRUE
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS deaths FROM pvpr_kills WHERE killed = 'Gutterknife' AND milestone = 'default') AS C ON TRUE
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT killed, COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE player = 'Gutterknife' GROUP BY killed ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1) AS D ON TRUE
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT player, COUNT(*) AS kills FROM pvpr_kills WHERE killed = 'Gutterknife' GROUP BY player ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1) AS E ON TRUE
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong if it's failing. You're joining all the tables on `A`.

Comment: I know I'm doing something wrong @FreshPrinceOfSO. I am not the best at SQL, so I want to know how to do what I want.

Comment: It might be better if you post the table structure. as well. and also describe what data you want

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to handle the case where there are no query results in your application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the subqueries.  I think the problem is the driver query:

```
FROM (SELECT player, score
      FROM pvpr_scores
      WHERE player = 'Neutronix' AND milestone = 'default'
     ) AS A . . .
```

If nothing matches this query, then the there are no rows to match in the other queries.

I'm not quite sure how to fix this.  I suppose you could do something like this:

```
FROM (select 'Neutronix' as player) t left outer join
     (SELECT player, score
      FROM pvpr_scores
      WHERE player = 'Neutronix' AND milestone = 'default'
     ) AS A
     on t.player = a.player left outer join . . .
```

And then change the `join` conditions in the rest of the `from` clause to `t.` instead of `a.`.

Comment: I tried changing all of the joins to `ON TRUE` and the joins don't work if the query returns a null set.

`[Err] 1048 - Column 'killed' cannot be null` -- This is when the C subquery returns null for the killed column.

Comment: @simplyianm . . . Can you reproduce this on SQL Fiddle.  I see nothing in the query that says that "'killed'` cannot be null".  SQL definitely allows you to left join an empty table to an existing table without generating an error.  Are you perhaps inserting this into a table where one of the columns is `not null`?

Comment: I am using a select, so I am not sure why it would be not null. The pvpr_kills table has `killed` as `NOT NULL`, though.

Comment: Anyways, I've produced a working query that's probably terrible code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running a sub select on the FROM - you could just a straight FROM scores.

You can also have multiple conditions on the 'ON' clause - e.g. ON b.player = a.player and b.milestone = a.milestone.

Rather than sub-selects you can use SUM and IF combined to give you the results - e.g. SUM( IF( row not null, 1, 0)) - this essentially sums 1's and 0's.

Obviously this isn't tested, but I'd approach your query along the lines of:

```
SELECT scores.player,
        scores.score,
        sum(if(kills.player is not null, 1, 0) as kills,
        sum(if(deaths.player is not null, 1, 0) as deaths
        killed.kills as most_killed,
        killed.killed as most_killed_count,
        killed_by.kills as most_killed_by_count,
        killed_by.killed as most_killed_by
FROM pvpr_scores as scores
LEFT JOIN pvpr_kills as kills
    on kills.player = player
    and kills.milestone = scores.milestone
LEFT JOIN pvpr_deaths as deaths
    on deaths.player = player
    and deaths.milestone = scores.milestone
LEFT JOIN (SELECT killed, player, count(killed) as kills
            FROM kills
            GROUP BY killed, player
            HAVING MAX( count(killed) ) ) as killed
    ON killed.player = scores.player
LEFT JOIN (SELECT killed, player, count(player) as kills
            FROM kills
            GROUP BY player, killed
            HAVING MAX( count(player) ) ) as killed_by
    ON killed_by.killed = scores.player

WHERE scores.player = 'neutronix'
  AND scores.milestone = 'default'

   GROUP BY scores.player
```